# Yep nope conditionally loading google web fonts

Tags: modernizr, google-webfonts, yepnope

I'm completely new to using Yep Nope within Modernzr and having some difficulties.

I'm wondering what the syntax would be to all me to do the following:

- Use yep nope to check for webfont support
- if so, append the url string to the head of the document to load the remote css file.

Something like isn't working - or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

```
yepnope({
  test : Modernizr.fontface
  yep : [
       $('<link href=\'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700|Oswald:300,400,700\' rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\'>').appendTo($('head'));
  ]
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I hope you've figured this out already, but in case you haven't:

You're attempting to run a JS statement as an item in an array. That won't work in any JS context that I know of. The first step I tried was to remove the jQuery call, and specify the raw URL to the CSS instead, like this:

```
yepnope({
    test: Modernizr.fontface,
    yep: [
      'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700|Oswald:300,400,700'
    ]
});
```

This loads the stylesheet, but throws an error because YepNope thinks it's a JS file. The fix for this is to include the YepNope CSS prefix plugin (you can find it in the Github repo [here](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/prefixes/yepnope.css-prefix.js)). Then you can do this:

```
yepnope({
    test: Modernizr.fontface,
    yep: [
      'css!//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700|Oswald:300,400,700'
    ]
});
```

I've tested, and it works great.

You can also use this method with Modernizr.load (if you're using a custom build of Modernizr). All you have to do is include any YepNope plugins after you include Modernizr. It's smart enough to delegate the appropriate calls to YepNope.

As a side note, notice I removed the "http:" from the second code block. This is called a "protocol relative URL". It allows the loading to occur based on your current protocol. That means it will load "**http**://fonts.googleapis..." if you're on an insecure domain, and load "**https**://fonts.googleapis..." if on a secure domain.

Comment: Hi there, how/where exactly do I add the css plugin for yepnope? I'm using Modernizr of which yepnope is now a part.

Comment: Modernizr doesn't include YepNope by default, but since you've got a build that includes it, you can just include the CSS plugin after you include Modernir, like this:
`<script src="custom-modernizr.js"></script><script src="components/yepnope/prefixes/yepnope.css-prefix.js"></script>`

Modernizr is smart enough to delegate all yepnope calls to YepNope itself, letting you use any of those plugins without hassle.

Sorry for the really long delay (DNS issues, I couldn't log in).